# Facebook share shows blank page after share

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using FB.ui to share a link:

This is my code

```
FB.ui({
     method: 'feed', 
     link: 'link',
     picture: 'picture',
     name: 'name',
     caption: 'title',
     description: 'share_text'
}
```

I am testing this inside the Facebook Application on IOS. So its a facebook canvas application. The share works fine, but after i click share i get a blank window with a cancel button. If i click the cancel button i am back to the website. From what i can tell, the popup being opened by FB.ui doesn't gets closed after share.

Thanks,
Radu

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the comment on response, on the graph documentation you have a callback function.

Maybe IOS don't like to see this callback function ignored. what if you try with :

```
FB.ui({
     method: 'feed', 
     link: 'link',
     picture: 'picture',
     name: 'name',
     caption: 'title',
     description: 'share_text'
}, function () {});
```

Comment: I already have a callback function. The weird thing is that the callback is executed when i open the popup, not after its closed. So method: feed is kinda buggy on facebook mobile app.